Authentication not working in blazor server app
so i am trying to implement authentication with microsoft in an existing blazor server app, that is made to run on an IIS and i also debug the site using IIS express.
I have checked out a lot of tutorials and the microsoft documentation and it does not work in my app still.
I have added a button to my login page, that redirects me to the microsoft login page. Because i was running into a wall with the authentication, i made a empty template in VS 2022 to check if it works and then compare it to my own app.
I have done that and essentially just copied the necessary libraries, services and IIS express options to my app.
I am using the AspNetCore authentication libraries as well as the Microsoft.Identity.Web libraries.
Now i have the situation where authentication works in the template project, no problem, while it fails in my own app.
I turned on trace logging to my appsetting for the following libs:
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "Trace"

Now in my template project i get this output:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {key} with purposes ('path\to\project', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Cookies', 'v2').
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was successfully authenticated.

While in my own project i get this:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector: Trace: Performing unprotect operation to key {key} with purposes ('path\to\project', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Cookies', 'v2').
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: OpenIdConnect was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed

Now to clarify:
the key is the same in both outputs and the paths to the project are correct in both.
I couldn't find any helpfull answer when searching for this error in the logs of my project, so i am hoping that maybe someone knows what the problem could be.
If any additional info is needed like for example the services i am using or the implementation of the button, the routes or the mainlayout or everything above, let me know and i will edit this question accordingly.
